# Do RESTful API controllers typically only provide resources related to their own type?

Tags: rest, api-design

Let's say my API has the following routes:

```
GET /theaters
GET /theaters/:id
GET /theaters/:id/movies
GET /movies
GET /movies/:id
GET /movies/:id/theaters
```

And then I have the following controllers with the listed methods:

```
TheaterController
    list
    show

MovieController
    list
    show
```

I'm trying to decide in which controllers the remaining requests would best be handled from a strict RESTful perspective. Would this

```
TheaterController
    listMoviesByTheater (handles GET /theaters/:id/movies)

MovieController
    showTheatersByMovie (handles GET /movies/:id/theaters)
```

or this

```
TheaterController
    listByMovie (handles GET /movies/:id/theaters)

MovieController
    listByTheater (handles GET /theaters/:id/movies)
```

be more RESTful? If neither is more RESTful, which is a more common approach?

Basically, the question boils down to whether TheaterController should only provide access to Theater resources and MovieController should only provide access to Movie resources.

Answer (score 5):

REST doesn't have anything to say about which controller services which URL.

From a purely hierarchical perspective, your first example makes more sense because the first (most general) level in the URL is being handled by its respective controller.

i.e.

```
/theaters/:id/movies -- belongs in the Theaters controller, and

/movies/:id/theaters -- belongs in the Movies controller.
```

But that has nothing to do with REST.  The whole point of REST is that a resource identified by a specific URL can be located *anywhere.*

Comment: Personally, I disagree. I think the hierarchy of the URL doesn't matter to the controller. It's just a mapping. I prefer to determine based on what resource gets returned. So if the resource being returned is a Movie then you can find the code in the MovieController regardless of where in URL it appears.

Comment: That works too.  The important thing is to be consistent enough so that the next programmer can follow your work.  Which controller does an Invoice ViewModel go into?

Comment: Is that a trick question?  I'll say, umm, the InvoiceController?

Comment: So you want one controller for every output artifact, then.  That works, I guess.  But perhaps a Reports controller makes just as much sense.

Comment: I see what you're saying. That sounds perfectly reasonable.